# Can't connect to IIS 7 management

Tags: windows, iis, remote-access

I have Windows Server 2008 running on one of my computers, and I have IIS 7 running on it. It is hosting my web page just fine, but when I try to use the remote managment for IIS 7 or even if I try to connect and edit my website remotely using Visual Web Developer 2008, it can't seem to find the server. Remote desktop works just fine, and other things work well also. I diabled the windows firewall and it still won't work. Just to let everyone know, I do have Norton Endpoint Protection installed on it. If you have a solution, please let me know.

Thanks

P.S. When I say remote, it isn't across the world somewhere. My server is on the same local network as my development computer. I also have a Linksys router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah thanks Igal. I figured it out. I had to install the IIS Managment feature on the IIS web server role. After that I also had to enable remote managment. it is working fine now.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have configured every thing as explaind in [Remote Administration for IIS Manager](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/158/remote-administration-for-iis-manager/). And a [lighter tutorial](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/159/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7/).